# How to integrate JSON response - pageable with jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, json, api, datatables, struts2

I am working with an API which provides the total data from database in JSON response. Along with data I am also getting few fields which are used for pagination.

```
{
  "data": [{----},{----},{----}],
  "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false,
            "empty": false
        },
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 200,
    "totalElements": 1988,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 10,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "empty": false
}
```

As the default size is 10 I am getting 10 values in array. But how do I access the next set of data in my DataTable.
What is the correct way to implement pagination depending on the JSON response in DataTable

Datatable code:

```
$("#k_table_1").dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'myAjaxUrl',
    "aoColumns": [
        {"mDataProp": "column1"},
        {"mDataProp": "column2"},
        {"mDataProp": "column3"},
        {"mDataProp": "column4"},
        {"mDataProp": "column5"},
        {"mDataProp": "column6"},
    ],
    "order": [[5, "desc"]]
});
```

At server side:

```
List<UserBean> aaData = new ArrayList<UserBean>(); // getter and setters added
JSONObject ResponseJson = new JSONObject();
ResponseJson = callApi("http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080/getData?size=10&page=0");
aaData = getUsersList(ResponseJson);  // puts JSON data in bean object
```

I am following this article: http://known-anton.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-jquerydata-table-with-struts2.html

but I am only able to display first 10 data, with only 1 page in page numbers and "Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries" as footer

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your DataTable code. But my suggestion is to use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). With this model, your server makes the requests to the 3rd party API - and it configures those requests based on the information provided in the DataTables [Ajax request](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters). These DataTables requests are automatically sent (if you are using `serverSide: true`) whehever the user clicks on one of the DataTables pagination buttons.

Comment: You are using Struts, so I guess you have a servlet container which could act as this intermediary. (1) It receives the DataTables request I mentioned above, (2) it translates that into the required URL for your API, (3) it gets the API's JSON response, (4) it reformats that into the JSON structure [required by DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Comment: @andrewJames I have added the datatable code and server side code also. My datatable code includes serverSide: true. what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you are missing steps (1), (2), and (4).

Comment: @andrewJames I think you did not checked the updated code.
1. "sAjaxSource": 'myAjaxUrl' (Calling my action servlet for processing)
2. ResponseJson = callApi("myAPIUrl") - This is calling the api to get the reponse inJSONObject format 
3. aaData = getUsersList(ResponseJson);  - It reformats the JSON structure in required format.

I have written comments instead of pasting the whole code.

Comment: I saw your updates before I wrote my previous comment. I looked at your updates again, just now. I still don't see any of the code for steps (1), (2) or (4) in your question, though. I don't even see any comments referring to those steps. I think maybe we are talking about different things?

Comment: There is no information in your question which would allow the community to help you with the specific problem you mention: "_I am only able to display first 10 data, with only 1 page in page numbers and "Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries" as footer_". Maybe you can ask a new question focusing on that specific problem?